# Pseudo Focus in CSS does not work on all objects

Tags: html, css

I have three contact fields on my website and i want that they get a thicker border when they are selected. I tried to solve that issue with field:focus... but the problem that I have now is that this thing only works with one of the three fields.

```css
.contactForm {
  background-color: rgb(118, 143, 197);
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 140px;
}

.contactForm p {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.contactFormHeading {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.contactFormHeading p {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.contactFormContent {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 270%;
}

.contactFormInput {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.contactFormInput:focus {
  border-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  border-width: 0.25rem;
}

.contactFormMessage {
  height: 140px;
}

input.contactFormSubmit[type="submit"] {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="columns six">
  <input class="contactFormInput" type="text" placeholder="Dein Name *" required="required" />
  <input class="contactFormInput" type="text" placeholder="Deine Email *" required="required" />
  <textarea class="contactFormInput contact-message" placeholder="Deine Nachricht *" required="required"></textarea>
  <input class="contactFormSubmit" type="submit" value="Nachricht senden" />
</div>
```

I have added two more pictures to the question

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bJ0i.png)

```
    .contactFormInput {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}


.contactFormInput:focus,
input.contactFormInput:focus {
    border: 1px solid rgb(30,30,30);
    background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
}

.contactFormMessage {
    height: 140px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: They are working in all fields for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have now should work.

It's possible there is some other css or js conflicting.

Try defining a default border on your `.contactFormInput` class then use `:focus` to modify that border.

```
.contactFormInput {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}


.contactFormInput:focus {
    border-color: rgb(30,30,30);
    border-width: 0.25rem;
}
```

Comment: It still does not work.

The first two input fields are ligthning blue and the last is black


I have added two more pictures to the question